# How to find the smallest triangular number greater than or equal to N?

Tags: math, number-theory

I know how to find the nearest triangular number:
m = floor(sqrt(2*N)
T = m*(m+1)/2
But that returns the triangular number closest to N.
I want the nearest triangular number greater than or equal to N.
So if I input 7, I want 10, not 6.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate `m` for corresponding quadratic equation `m*(m+1)/2 >= N`, round it up (use ceiling) and get needed result.

Python example:

```
import math

def uppertri(n):
    #dis = math.sqrt(1 + 8 * n)
    #m = math.ceil((dis-1)/2)
    #better variant proposed by Mark Dickinson (for Python 3.8+)
    m = (math.isqrt(8*n) + 1) // 2
    return m*(m+1)//2

for i in range(1, 30):
    uppertri(i)
    print(i, uppertri(i), end = "; ")

1 1; 2 3; 3 3; 4 6; 5 6; 6 6; 7 10; 8 10; 9 10; 10 10; 11 15; 12 15; 13 15; 14 15; 
15 15; 16 21; 17 21; 18 21; 19 21; 20 21; 21 21; 22 28; 23 28; 24 28; 25 28; 26 28;
27 28; 28 28; 29 36;
```

Comment: `m = (math.isqrt(8*n) + 1) // 2` would also work here, and avoids the potential imprecision from use of floating-point.

Comment: (And it's probably not helpful for the OP, but I guess the code-golf version of this looks something like `uppertri=lambda n:(math.isqrt(8*n)+1|1)**2//8`)